# Nested UITableView returning cell but not displaying it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to make an expandable menu with nested `UITableViews` where clicking on a category expands to show the items in that category (this part works now) where each item is a custom `UITableViewCell` which has a label for the item name and another `UITableView` (tvInner) below the label. When clicking on the item, I want to update my menu data to that custom cell (this part works now) and then I want that custom cell to add another cell (cell_itemrow) to that inner `UITableView` (tvInner) and display it (this is the part that doesn't work).

**VC_Main** (My ViewController class that has my outer `UITableView` (**tvOuter**):

```
import UIKit

struct Collapsed{
    var category_opened = Bool()
    var category_id = Int()
    var category_name = String()
    var items = [Item]()
}

struct Item{
    var name = String()
    var rows = [Row]()
}

struct Row{
    var size: Int
}

struct FlatItem {
    var itemid: Int
    var category_id: Int
    var category_name: String
    var name: String
}

class VC_Main: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tvOuter: UITableView!

    var collapsedMenu = [Collapsed]()

    var flatMenu = [
        FlatItem(itemid: 0, category_id: 0, category_name: "category1", name: "item1"),
        FlatItem(itemid: 2, category_id: 0, category_name: "category1", name: "item2"),
        FlatItem(itemid: 3, category_id: 0, category_name: "category1", name: "item3"),
        FlatItem(itemid: 4, category_id: 1, category_name: "category2", name: "item4"),
        FlatItem(itemid: 7, category_id: 1, category_name: "category2", name: "item5"),
        FlatItem(itemid: 9, category_id: 1, category_name: "category2", name: "item6")]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let mapping = Dictionary(grouping: flatMenu, by: { $0.category_id })
        collapsedMenu = mapping.map {
            Collapsed(
                category_opened: false,
                category_id: $0.key,
                category_name:  $0.value.first?.category_name ?? "",
                items: $0.value.map { Item(name: $0.name, rows: []) }
            )
        }
        .sorted { $0.category_id < $1.category_id }       
        tvOuter.delegate = self
        tvOuter.dataSource = self
        tvOuter.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

extension VC_Main: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return collapsedMenu.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if collapsedMenu[section].category_opened == true{
            return collapsedMenu[section].items.count + 1
        }else{
            return 1
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0{ // category cell type
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_category") else {return UITableViewCell()}
            cell.textLabel?.text = collapsedMenu[indexPath.section].category_name
            return cell
        }else{ // item cell type
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_item") as! cell_item
            cell.itemdata = collapsedMenu[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row - 1]
            cell.lblItemName.text = collapsedMenu[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row - 1].name
            return cell
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0{ // we clicked a category heading (cell_category)
            if collapsedMenu[indexPath.section].category_opened == true{
                collapsedMenu[indexPath.section].category_opened = false
            }else{
                collapsedMenu[indexPath.section].category_opened = true
            }
            let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
            tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none)
        }else{ // we clicked an item (cell_item)
            collapsedMenu[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row - 1].rows.append(Row(size: 0))
            let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
            tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none)
        }
    }
}
```

My custom `UITableViewCell` class **cell_item** (which holds the inner `UITableView` (**tvInner**) to hold more inner `UITableViewCells` (**cell_itemrow**) for the item rows:

```
import UIKit

class cell_item: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var ivItemImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblItemName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tvInner: UITableView!

    var itemdata = Item()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setUpTable()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setUpTable()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        //tvInner?.frame = CGRectMake(0.2, 0.3, self.bounds.size.width-5, self.bounds.size.height-5)
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func setUpTable(){
        tvInner.delegate = self
        tvInner.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemdata.rows.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_itemrow") as! cell_itemrow
        cell.lblRowLabel.text = itemdata.name
        let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
        tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none) // play around with this animation
        return cell
    }
}
```

**What I've confirmed so far:**

- flatMenu is populating correctly
- collapsedMenu is being created correctly
- The outer TableView is being shown correctly
- The category cells are being shown correctly
- When clicking on a category_cell, it expands correctly and shows all items for that category
- When clicking an item_cell, it appends a row to the item data structure (**collapsedMenu**) in VC_Main's didSelectRowAt indexPath
- VC_Main's cellForRowAt indexPath update's the item data to that cell (**itemdata**) and returns the cell
- After that, cell_item receives the data for that item and knows that 1 cell_itemrow needs to be added to the tvInner.
- cell_item's cellForRowAt indexPath creates a cell_itemrow cell (and that cell is not nil)
- cell_item's cellForRowAt indexPath returns the cell

> But then that cell is either not added or not shown

**What I want to achieve:**

- When clicking an item_cell, it should add a cell_itemrow to that item_cell's tvInner, then reload as necessary and show the cell

I've set up my `UITableViews` and `UITableViewCells` in Main.storyboard.

**Alternatively, if there's a way to achieve this without using an inner `UITableView`, I'd like to know how to do that. When the item_cell is touched I want to add a new row with a delete button and label, and clicking the delete button of a row should remove it from the data structure and remove its row from the view**

Comment: `tvInner` won't auto-size the cell inside of which it is sitting, as it's a subclass of a scroll view and probably instead adjusts its inner scrollable surface to match the height of superview. Do you anyhow solve that problem?

Comment: How can I solve that?

Comment: Nesting a UITableView inside a UITableViewCell is problematic because you're nesting a UIScrollView inside a UIScrollView, in effect, which is _at best_ discouraged. It sounds like you're over-complicating your UI.

Comment: 1. Calculate the sum of heights of cells in `tvInner`. 2. Return it as a height of corresponding cell in `tvOuter`'s `tableView(_ tableView: heightForRowAt indexPath:)` method

Comment: @particleman Can you suggest a simpler way to add rows to the UITableViewCell onTouch? I'd also like to add a delete button to each row and be able to delete the rows dynamically.

Comment: The table view is the view of the current state of your data source. As such, if a touch interaction with a cell changes the data source, then the table view can reflect this (adding new cells, deleting cells, adding sections, etc.). It's up to you to decide how to best visualize your data. You can load custom cells that have the appearance of being subcells by visual indentation, for example.

Comment: The reason I didn't do it like that is because I want separators between items but not between sub-items, to make it clear that the sub-items are rows of that item, and I thought separators would need to be all on or all off. But that sounds like a better idea so I'll try to do it in a way that I can disable the separators of the sub-item cells.

Comment: I've done exactly that before. Use custom cells to your advantage where individual items can have distinct separator characteristics. You might need to have your delegate play a role in determining the cell height (the default will include a separator), but since it's based on the model, it's pretty trivial to implement. Ultimately, the touch event handling is far simpler to achieve the "expanding" cell effect you're trying to achieve.